# Cannot establish proper RS485 communication

Tags: c, avr, atmega, rs485

I was trying serial communication using `ATmega32`. First i used RS232, using USB-to-RS232 to establish receive and transmit using serial terminal(in my case tera term). Whatever i send from serial terminal Atmega32 echo it back.

for eg.  i send `Hello\r` and i receive 'Hello\r'

It is working fine.

Then i used RS485, using USB-to-RS485 to establish communication with ATmega32 but i only get 1st character in return.

for eg. if i send `Hello` i get back `H`. if i send `planets` i get only `p` in return.

Here is the code:

```
void Delay(int ms)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<ms;i++)
    _delay_ms(1);

}

void UART_Init(unsigned int baud)
{
    UBRRH = (unsigned char)(baud >> 8);
    UBRRL = (unsigned char)baud;

    UCSRB = (1<<RXEN)  | (1<<TXEN) | (1<<RXCIE);
    UCSRC = (1<<URSEL) | (3<<UCSZ0);
}

void UART_Transmit(unsigned char data)
{
    UDR = data;
    while ( !( UCSRA & (1<<UDRE) ) );
}


void USART_Transmit_String( char *string)
{
    while (*string != 0)
    UART_Transmit(*string++);
}


void Clear_Buffer(char *string)
{
    while (*string != '\0')
    {
        *string = 0;
        string++;
    }
}

ISR(USART_RXC_vect)
{
    uartBuff[datapos] = UDR;
    if (uartBuff[datapos] == '\r')
    {
        eos = 1;
    }
    datapos++;
    if (datapos > SIZE)
    {
        datapos = 0;
        Clear_Buffer(uartBuff);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    _delay_ms(1000);
    UART_Init(103);
    sei();
    LED_Enable();
    LED_High();
    Delay(100);
    LED_Low();
    Delay(100);

    RE_DE_Enable();
    RE_DE_High();
    USART_Transmit_String("Hello World");
    UART_Transmit(0x0d);
    UART_Transmit('\n');
    Delay(1000);
    datapos = 0;
    eos = 0;
    RE_DE_Low();
    while (1) 
    {
        if (strstr(uartBuff,"led on\r"))
        {
            LED_High();
        }
        if (strstr(uartBuff,"led off\r"))
        {
            LED_Low();
        }

        if (eos == 1)
        {
            RE_DE_High();
            uartBuff[datapos] = '\0';
            USART_Transmit_String("\r\n");
            USART_Transmit_String(uartBuff);
            USART_Transmit_String("\r\n");
            Clear_Buffer(uartBuff);
            datapos = 0;
            eos = 0;
            RE_DE_Low();
        }

    }
}
```

Why this type of abnormality?

How to rectify this error?

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: strstr() is a bug and only works by accident, rx_buff does not contain a zero-terminated C string.  The Clear_Buffer() calls are pretty poisonous as well, they'll randomly throw away received data.

Comment: All very hardware dependent. Are you running full or half duplex, and is it the same each end? RE_DE sounds a bit strange. you usually want then opposite so only one is enabled. For half duplex you can leave RX on and it will receive what you transmit. Can be useful for debug.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for your reply. As i have tried the same code for rs232 and i have done similar thing with that where i used `led on` and `led off` to turn led on and off and it just worked fine. So now whats the problem with rs485?

Comment: @WilliamJBagshaw I am using half duplex and if RE_DE is low it will receive and if RE_DE is high it will transmit. Both RE and DE are connected to same pin.

Comment: Without going into detail, I think it makes sense to remove the buffer checking operations from that ISR, and move them into the main loop. Use the ISR only to do the most critical things, like storing the incoming bytes... Also, shouldn't that check there "(datapos > SIZE)" be "(datapos >= SIZE)"?

Comment: @rel After i store the data into the buffer i need to increment the `datapos`. if i put the buffer checking operation for `\r` in main it might miss that beacuse the `datapos` is incremented. One option is to check for the whole buffer in loop, But i don't thing it will matter much as led blink was just for checking that data is checked correctly. it will just set `eos = 1` if i receive `\r`. Moreover i have defined SIZE as 250 and my datapos's data type is `int` so that will not be an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting a bit confused on who is transmitting what in reviewing this post so have the following comments:

1) simplify the Atmel code to only stream out "Hello World %d" + CR and keep incrementing the line #. For now, keep com speed @ 9600 baud. Does this traffic from the Atmel to the USB RS485 dongle get received with 100% success? Do not continue till this does.

2) Which RS485 transceiver are you using in this design for the Atmel side? There is a lot of garbage on the market and not all transceivers are created equal.

3) Which USB RS485 dongle are you using? As per (2), only few are reliable. If using the clear FTDI USB RS485 dongle then review very carefully on which RS485 transceiver is embossed inside the plastic. FTDI has admitted they put out some flaky dongle cables based on the Sipex transceiver. From our brief review, believe the design was at fault and not the transceiver. However, regardless, now that the dongle is sealed, the same buggy dongle cannot be corrected.

We build some solid adapters but do not wish to turn this into an ad so let us see if we can debug your case. Post more details to continue.

Wish to add that on your RS485 receiver pin, be sure there is a local pull-up resistor to +3v3. This is required to have a high state on the Atmel receive of the UART when the RS485 receiver is DISABLED. That is, when the RS485 receiver is disabled, the RX pin is high-z. A value of 10k is known to be good and the value is not critical but the pull-up is recommended.

Update

I think I understand the point of view of your project. Please correct if I am wrong. Are you attempting to use Teraterm + USB RS485 dongle to send out text to the Atmel over RS485 and wish to have the Atmel send back the data to your Teraterm? If yes, then the results are logical if you are typing this data in Teraterm. Please confirm this setup.

That is, are you typing "Hello world" and expecting to receive this text back?

The issue with this idea is that the PC is sending out the data faster than you can type. Instead, review on how you can use Teraterm to send out in a macro form the entire string in a block. Only this method will work for your idea. When you are typing, Teraterm is sending out (aka flushing the tx buffer) the "H" over the RS485  interface, etc. so you will not receive the entire string in a single block receive.

Consider a macro with Teraterm to send out "Planets", etc. in a single send. The key point is not delay between each character that you wish to send.

Comment: After going through your post thoroughly.. i found that because i didn't put any pull up on RX my communication was not working. Thanks

Comment: You will be rewarded after 15 hours.

Answer (score 0):

485 requires precise line control when transmitting the data. UDRE means the data can be loaded. TXC means the data has been sent. The line should released only after the last bit has been transmitted. I believe this is the reason it works in rs232 and fails in rs485.

Comment: Sorry that's not the case. In `UART_Transmit()` i wrote        `while ( !( UCSRA & (1<<TXC) ) );` in place of  `while ( !( UCSRA & (1<<UDRE) ) )`. What happened is my transmit also din not happen properly i.e while i used `UDRE` i could see `Hello World` in terminal but after using `TXC`, `Hello World` did not transmit completely.

Comment: Please see this link: https://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/uart-rs485. It is pretty much the same case as you are trying to achieve and it does use TXC. Keep in mind that TXC should be polled at the end of transmission not after each byte. The best way would of course be to see what you transmit with a scope but I guess this option is not available.

Comment: In the link you provided, that person is receiving the data one by one. Where as in my case i wanted the whole string to echo back not character by character. Though i din try this code by i m sure this will work. But this is not what i wanted. I want whole string and then echo it back...

Comment: Your initial "Hello world" includes a delay which allows the whole string to be sent. Provided that you receive the the whole string these kind of issues are mostly tied to the RE line control. The easiest way to verify this would be to run your original code with UDRE and all but add the same delay in echo before releasing the line. If you manage to receive the data the issue is line control.

Comment: Yes i did thought about this and added 2ms delay before echoing back but nothing happend

Comment: It should be after you echo back not before. The delay should come before you release the line. Did you try that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176951/discussion-between-hedgehog81-and-devjeet-mandal).